# Need some help clarifying a piece of code which im trying to complete C++

Tags: c++, class, shapes

Below is the code to a "rhombus.cpp" file which i am to complete. But first i would like to highlight this area " Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius) : Shape(point){".. my question is what exactly occurs here when in the compiler? the : Shape(point) is completely new to me so i am unsure of what to do, especially when i am to call this in the int main. And if what i have placed under the comment of //place your code here and add comments, etc is correct in what ive done? Your help is much appreciated!

```
#include "rhombus.h"

Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius) : Shape(point){
// constructs a Rhombus of radius around a point in 2D space
if((radius>centroid.getX()/2) || (radius>centroid.getX()/2))
{
    cout << "Object must fit on screen." << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}
// place your code here and add comments that describe your understanding of        what is happening
this->radius = radius;
plotVertices();
}

int Rhombus::area()
{
// returns the area of a Rhombus
return 0;
}

int Rhombus::perimeter()
{
// returns the perimeter of a Rhombus
return 0;
}

void Rhombus::plotVertices()
{
// a formula for rotating a point around 0,0 is
// x' = x * cos(degrees in radians) - y * sin(degrees in radians)
// y' = y * cos(degrees in radians) + x * sin(degrees in radians)
// the coordinates for point A are the same as the centroid adjusted for the    radius
// the coordinates for point B are determined by rotating point A by 90 degrees
// the coordinates for point C are determined by rotating point A by 180 degrees
// the coordinates for point C are determined by rotating point A by 270 degrees
// remember that 0,0 is at the top left, not the bottom left, corner of the console

// place your code here and add comments that describe your understanding of what is happening
}
```

Rhombus.h

```
#include "shape.h"

class Rhombus : public Shape
{
int radius;

void plotVertices();
public:
Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius = 10);
int area();
int perimeter();
};
```

Shape.h

```
enter #pragma once
#include "console.h"
#include "vertex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

class Shape
{
list<Vertex>::iterator itr;
protected:
list<Vertex> vertices;
Vertex centroid;
void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
Shape(Vertex point);
double round(double x);
public:
void drawShape();
virtual int area() = 0;
virtual int perimeter() = 0;
virtual void outputStatistics();
void rotate(double degrees);
void scale(double factor);
};
```

Comment: Does rhombus.h include a shape.h? Also look at the line `class rhombus` in rhombus.h.  You should look in your literature for inheritance.

Comment: Hi and yes it does, ive edited my post to include it, i can also attach the shape.cpp if necessary. inheritance is a topic ive barely touched upon but ill have to look into it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line
    Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius)

Is the constructor for your class. It tells you you can instantiate/create a Rhombus object like

```
int main(){
     Vertex v;
     Rhombus rhomb(v, 3);
```

This object creation is often called instantiation.

The extra Shape

```
 Rhombus::Rhombus(Vertex point, int radius): Shape(point)
```

Describes *how* to create the Rhombus object. Namely by calling a constructor in `Shape` that accepts a `Vertex` argument. Then it runs the rest of the code in the constructor. This is needed because Rhombus inherits Shape as you will find in `rhombus.h`.

The key stuff you need to read up on is inheritance. This is likely covered quite early.

Comment: Thanks Captain Giraffe, you made it look so simple i almost feel slightly embarrased. But thanks again for including the terminology, i shall now have a further look into this as im required to create numerous shapes with featured scaling and rotation included too. nightmare. Thank you again!